# How to group user actions within the same session?

Tags: audit, session-management, user-tracking

I'm working on enterprise application where it's needed to audit all user actions (data modification, settings changing etc.) within their work session.

What is the best way to group all that actions by the session (what actions were done during specified user session)?

There should be taken into account that the same user can have several concurrent sessions, using sessionID explicitly is not secure (other user can view audit log and get sessionId that is still actual), sessionId can be regenerated during the session (in case of password or privelege changing).

The only idea that I have now is to generate additional identifier (uuid or something else) for the session and add it to the audit events information.
But I'm not sure that is the best possible option.